# MongoDB aggregate using distinct

Tags: mongodb

I have an aggregation that groups on a date and creates a sum.

```
db.InboundWorkItems.aggregate({
    $match: {
        notificationDate: {
            $gte: ISODate("2013-07-18T04:00:00Z")
        },
        dropType: 'drop'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            notificationDate: "$notificationDate"
        },
        nd: {
            $first: "$notificationDate"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        nd: 1
    }
})
```

The output is

```
"result" : [
    {
        "_id" : {
            "notificationDate" : ISODate("2013-07-18T04:00:00Z")
        },
        "nd" : ISODate("2013-07-18T04:00:00Z"),
        "count" : 484
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "notificationDate" : ISODate("2013-07-19T04:00:00Z")
        },
        "nd" : ISODate("2013-07-19T04:00:00Z"),
        "count" : 490
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "notificationDate" : ISODate("2013-07-20T04:00:00Z")
        },
        "nd" : ISODate("2013-07-20T04:00:00Z"),
        "count" : 174
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "notificationDate" : ISODate("2013-07-21T04:00:00Z")
        },
        "nd" : ISODate("2013-07-21T04:00:00Z"),
        "count" : 6
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "notificationDate" : ISODate("2013-07-22T04:00:00Z")
        },
        "nd" : ISODate("2013-07-22T04:00:00Z"),
        "count" : 339
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "notificationDate" : ISODate("2013-07-23T04:00:00Z")
        },
        "nd" : ISODate("2013-07-23T04:00:00Z"),
        "count" : 394
    },
    {
        "_id" : {
            "notificationDate" : ISODate("2013-07-24T04:00:00Z")
        },
        "nd" : ISODate("2013-07-24T04:00:00Z"),
        "count" : 17
    }
],
"ok" : 1
```

so far so good.  What I need to do now is to keep this, but also add a distinct in the criteria (for argument's sake I want to use AccountId).  The would yield me the count of the grouped dates only using distinct AccountId. Is distinct even possible within the aggregation framework?

Answer (score 0):

you can use two group commands in the pipeline, the first to group by accoundId, followed by second group that does usual operation. something like this:

```
db.InboundWorkItems.aggregate( 
  {$match: {notificationDate: {$gte: ISODate("2013-07-18T04:00:00Z")}, dropType:'drop' }}, 
  {$group: {_id:"accountId",notificationDate:"$notificationDate"}},
  {$group: {_id:1, nd: {$first:"$notificationDate"}, count:{$sum:1} }}, 
  {$sort:{nd:1}}  )
```

Comment: refer to the last row here which maps from SQL distinct to equivalent mongo operation: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/

Comment: This is definitely not working since the first group will get rid of the field notificationDate.

Comment: yup, sorry for overlooking that. so add notificationDate to first group. see edited answer.

Comment: this looks like a new addition, might be handy for problems like this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Comment: The collection distinct command has been around before the aggregation framework, unfortunately it gets key pairs from the index unlike the aggregation framework which can actually do a grouped distinct on fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.InboundWorkItems.aggregate({
    $match: {
        notificationDate: {
            $gte: ISODate("2013-07-18T04:00:00Z")
        },
        dropType: 'drop'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$AccountId",
        notificationDate: {
            $max: "$notificationDate"
        },
        dropType: {
            $max: "$dropType"
        }
    }

}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            notificationDate: "$notificationDate"
        },
        nd: {
            $first: "$notificationDate"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        nd: 1
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might actually be looking for a single group (English is a bit confusing) like so:

```
db.InboundWorkItems.aggregate({
    $match: {
        notificationDate: {
            $gte: ISODate("2013-07-18T04:00:00Z")
        },
        dropType: 'drop'
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            notificationDate: "$notificationDate", accountId: '$accountId'
        },
        nd: {
            $first: "$notificationDate"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        nd: 1
    }
})
```

I add the compound _id in the $group because of:

> The would yield me the count of the grouped dates only using distinct AccountId.

Which makes me think you want the grouped date count by account ID.